# Typescript AngularJS pdf API

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I think the title is weird but just says all i want.

I got the following API call

```
this.myAPI.get("/endpoint/toget/pdf/")
                    .then(response => {

                    }, function(error) {

                    });
```

The API response with a PDF file `not a link` but a PDF file. How do i capture that file and allow the user to `ng-click` and open the file?

Ideas.. Anyone?

Comment: Do you need to read it into your app? Can you not just have the ng-click use the browser to open the file?

Comment: @DanielCook if it was a link it would have been easy. I need to read it into the app

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you get a base64 string the following works perfect but sadly and obviously not in IE.

`window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + response.data.content);`